# Capture Image of Cursor Window

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscursor

Is it possible to capture an image of the NSCursor window? Here's my code

Get the raw value of the cursor window

```
let level = CGWindowLevelForKey(.CursorWindowLevelKey).int
```

I have a method that iterates through all windows on screen using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo and returns the window number of the Cursor window which is owned by "Window Server"

```
let number = self.windowNumber(level, screen: screen, options: nil) //returns proper window number
let frame = screen.frame //screen is the current NSScreen that the mouse is in. 

let cgimage = CGWindowListCreateImage(frame, .OptionIncludingWindow, CGWindowID(number), .Default)!
```

Convert to NSBitmapImageRep

```
let cursor = NSBitmapImageRep(CGImage: cgimage)
```

The screen shot of the cursor is then saved to the disk.

This works great with all other windows except the cursor where it saves a blank window. I have tried using a bunch of different types of frames as well but no go. I assume it is because CGWindowListCreateImage automatically omits the cursor window. Is it possible to stop it from omitting that? Maybe duplicate the window and capture that?

Other things I have tried

1. Getting the image using `NSCursor.currentCursor().image` but because my app is a background only app, I am forced to use `NSCursor.currentSystemCursor().image` which always returns a non-retina image.
2. Figuring out which `NSCursor.currentSystemCursor().image` is returning and trying to get the retina version... just no way to compare really which instance is brought back.

Comment: "Is it possible to capture an image of the NSCursor window" Clearly it is, since ScreenFlow does it. But I have no idea how. :)

Comment: @matt in video recording yes, that's actually fairly easy. But as a single image screen grab the Quartz display services don't allow for that, so the cursor must be composited on top. And it is very tricky when dealing with retina vs non-retina.

Comment: Fascinating. Maybe that's why Apple's Grab app doesn't show the cursor? I had no idea about this distinction. — What about SnapzProX? It shows the cursor correctly...

Comment: That's because SnapzProX uses currentSystemCursor which does not capture the retina version of the cursor. So it looks pixelated. This is what I first tried (listed #1 in my question).

Comment: Fascinating again. It sounds to me like this just a missing piece of functionality. Obviously a bug report / enhancement request to Apple is in order. Thanks for the explanations!